# Heroku: Run different webserver process on staging site?

Tags: heroku

I want to run a different webserver on one of my staging sites, which provides more debug-friendly error handling.  I'm wondering if/how this is possible without having to change the Procfile between my staging and production deployments.

I tried this:

```
web: newrelic-admin run-program python manage.py run_gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT -w 4 -k gevent 
debug: newrelic-admin run-program python manage.py runserver_plus 0.0.0.0:$PORT --threaded
```

And then scaling web to 0 and debug to 1, but its now clear to me from [this article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) that *web* is a special reserved keyword and that's the only process that gets http requests.  So is there any way to manage this without having to maintain a separate branch or the like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure you can.

As you note, you need to use the "web" process type.

Remember that process types are effectively just named commands: "Each process type is a declaration of a command that is executed when a dyno of that process type is started"

You control the command.

In a little test app, I just created a bin directory, added a file, and gave it execute permission - like this:

```
mkdir bin
vi bin/go.sh
chmod a+x bin/go.sh
```

The contents looked like this:

```
echo $*
echo $FOOBAR
thin --rackup config.ru start $*
```

I then modified my Procfile to look like this:

```
web: ~/bin/go.sh --port $PORT
```

I also added a config var to my app:

heroku config:add FOOBAR=123

I then looked at the logs after starting

`` 2013-03-14T11:49:42+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `~/bin/go.sh --port 47302`
   2013-03-14T11:49:43+00:00 app[web.1]: --port 47302
   2013-03-14T11:49:43+00:00 app[web.1]: 123
   2013-03-14T11:49:44+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up ``

Excellent.  Can you see what happened?

- When I started a web dyno, Heroku looked up the web process type and executed the command
- The command started my server, but before that, it printed both the parameters sent to it (--port XXX) and the FOOBAR environment variable (which will get set by the config var)

So I think that's all you need.  Just go write a bash script that, depending on a config var, executes a different command on staging vs production.  On staging, set the config var.  On production, don't.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate Heroku app to serve as your staging environment and use the same codebase (local git repo). See [Managing Multiple Environments for an App](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments)

Note that the specific task you're asking about involves changing the `Procfile`, so you may want to use a branch. In that case, you push branches like so (assuming multiple env as per the guide above):

```
$ git push heroku-staging <branch_name>:master --app staging_app_name
```

Comment: In sum: the answer to my question appears to be No.

Comment: The answer is "yes", if you setup a separate branch for your Procfile changes as I said above. The answer is "no", if you want to just use the means you described in your question.

Comment: Ah.  I was thinking in terms of the question I asked at the end of the body of my question, which explicitly excludes maintaining a separate branch. But you answered the question in the Title, which is legit I suppose. We're on the same page now--thanks for the response!  I'll have to look at whether maintaining a separate branch and constantly merging/rebasing it to update staging is worth the payoff here (I'm leaning toward probably not).

Comment: ah, I actually missed that part, sorry. Good luck